# Facebook Delete All Scores for the App

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

(T_T) sorry, I can't speak English well.

1. I try to delete scores for a player in unity3d
2. code

   FB.API("/me/scores", HttpMethod.DELETE, (IGraphResult result)=>
   {
   Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
   Debug.Log (result.Error);
   }
   );
3. result is success

   but
4. I try to Delete All scores for the app in unity3d
5. code

   FB.API("/1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx8/scores", HttpMethod.DELETE, (IGraphResult result)=>
   {
   Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
   Debug.Log (result.Error);
   }
   );
6. result is fail
   error message :
   I/Unity(14537): {"error":{"message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":15,"fbtrace_id":"A8vi0k7aBoA"}}
7. how to resolve [This method must be called with an app]

I referenced this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements?locale=en_US

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely it says

> This method should be called with App access token

You need to provide app_access_token with request and this also requires publishing permissions.
You can have a look here to know about app access token and you can make a graph api call to get it:

```
GET /oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Hope this helps